# How do you monitor DejaDup's progress?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I have "Backup" DejaDup app backing up my home folder to an encrypted external USB hard drive, but it takes hours. The GUI's "backup now" button is grayed out, indicating it's running, and Gnome says "starting scheduled backup". However, I have no idea how long it should take. Is there anyway to get progress info from DejaDup?

Top shows that the duplicity process is running with the option `--log-fd=16`. Duplicity's manpage indicates that this is the file descriptor of the log file it writes status updates to. However, if I run `tail -f 16`, I get the error `tail: no files remaining`. How do I read this log file descriptor?

Comment: There's a field you can click that says Details or More Info or something.  It's not real helpful but you can see file names scrolling by, at least indicating that something is happening.  This only seems to work when it says "scanning" or "backing up".

Comment: @Organic Marble, It only shows that when I manually initiate the backup. If it automatically starts, then that page shows "error a backup is already in progress" and doesn't show any detail.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/972194

Comment: @Cerin  Ah. Thanks for the info. I only use manual backups so I didn't know that.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can monitor it like this:

using ps, get the PID and the log fd, e.g.

```
$ ps aux | grep duplicity
username  12345 97.2  4.9 878235 345123 ?       Rsl  02:21  15:02 python2 /usr/bin/duplicity --exclude=/run/media/..... --tempdir=/home/username/.cache/deja-dup/tmp --log-fd=18
```

The PID is 12345, and the file descriptor is 18.

Then go to `/proc/PID/fd (/proc/12345/fd)` and instead of trying to tail the file descriptor 18, use cat or grep.

```
$ cat 18
```

This shows way too much info for me.  90% of it are my exclude globs.

```
$ grep "examining path" 18
```

works well for seeing which file is being examined.  If you look at the output, you can also focus on when it finds files match (and don't need backing up) or when they're different.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the solution provided by @RichardSchwarting I created the following command that checks if the process is running an does the cat on `/proc/x/fd/y`:

```
pid=$(pgrep -n duplicity); if [ $pid ]; then fd=$( ps -o cmd --no-headers $pid | sed -E 's/.+(log-fd=[0-9]+).?/\1/' | cut -f2 -d =); if [ $fd ]; then cat /proc/$pid/fd/$fd; else echo "fd not found"; fi else echo "pid not found"; fi
```

Comment: This just gives me "pid not found". Note, `duplicity` doesn't seem to run. It's `deja-dup` that's running.

Comment: @Cerin deja-dup is the UI, duplicity is doing the backup. The command only shows the log while the backup i.e. duplicity is running...

Comment: Some of you probably have duplicity being run by python, in which case the executable is `python`, not `duplicity`. So instead, try using `pid=$(pgrep -f duplicity); if [ $pid ]; then fd=$( ps -o cmd --no-headers $pid | sed -E 's/.+(log-fd=[0-9]+).?/\1/' | cut -f2 -d =); if [ $fd ]; then cat /proc/$pid/fd/$fd; else echo "fd not found"; fi else echo "pid not found"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

I enhanced the answer by Richard.
https://askubuntu.com/a/952872/359904

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep duplicity)/fd/$(ps aux | grep duplicity | perl -lne 'push @a,/fd=(\d+)/g;END{print "@a"}')
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462659/search-for-a-string-and-print-next-to-that-using-sed-awk