# Dejadup's progress gui missing in 17.10

Tags: backup, gui

Since updating to 17.10 on Wayland, whenever Dejadub starts an automatic backup the progress gui is missing. If I start a backup manually the progress gui is there, it is only missing if the backup starts automatically.

I have tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846318/how-do-you-monitor-dejadups-progress) but it is a lot of messing about and sometimes stops even though the backup is still running according to the processes#

Does anyone know to get the progress gui back up and running on automatic backups on Wayland?

Comment: I found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1697155). It says you can bring the progress window up by clicking on the "backup started" notification. I will need to wait 24 hours until my next scheduled backup to confirm.